# NoMethodError (undefined method `aasm_state') when saving a record

Tags: state-machine, aasm

When saving `payment request`, there is an error popping up:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `aasm_state' for #<PaymentRequestx::PaymentRequest:0x007f574d229df8>):
  activemodel (4.2.0) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
  aasm (4.11.0) lib/aasm/persistence/base.rb:36:in `aasm_read_state'
  aasm (4.11.0) lib/aasm/instance_base.rb:12:in `current_state'
  aasm (4.11.0) lib/aasm/persistence/active_record_persistence.rb:233:in `aasm_invalid_state?'
  aasm (4.11.0) lib/aasm/persistence/active_record_persistence.rb:225:in `block in aasm_validate_states'
  aasm (4.11.0) lib/aasm/persistence/active_record_persistence.rb:223:in `each'
  aasm (4.11.0) lib/aasm/persistence/active_record_persistence.rb:223:in `aasm_validate_states'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:427:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:189:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:189:in `block in simple'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
  activemodel (4.2.0) lib/active_model/validations.rb:395:in `run_validations!'
  activemodel (4.2.0) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:113:in `block in run_validations!'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
  activemodel (4.2.0) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:113:in `run_validations!'
  activemodel (4.2.0) lib/active_model/validations.rb:334:in `valid?'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/validations.rb:58:in `valid?'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/validations.rb:83:in `perform_validations'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/validations.rb:37:in `save'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in `block (2 levels) in save'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:347:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:344:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in `block in save'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:301:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:285:in `save'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bundler/gems/payment_requestx-7836ca37b30f/app/controllers/payment_requestx/payment_requests_controller.rb:45:in `create'
```

The error occurs when saving in `payment_requests_controller.rb`:

```
 if @payment_request.save
```

Before that, there is a saving of `payment request` successfully. What's the problem with gem `AASM`?

Answer (score 2):

[Make sure you've added](https://github.com/aasm/aasm#column-name--migration) the column required by AASM with a migration.

Answer (score 0):

When using AASM, you need to include AASM to targeted model.

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AASM

  aasm do
    state :sleeping, initial: true
    state :running

    event :run, after_commit: :notify_about_running_job do
      transitions from: :sleeping, to: :running
    end
  end

  def notify_about_running_job
    ...
  end
end
```

after that you need to generate a migration, so the targeted model database table has this **aasm_state** field.

```
  def self.up
    add_column :jobs, :aasm_state, :string
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :jobs, :aasm_state
  end
end
```

after migration, AASM should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't want to add column **aasm_state** on your table.

> Just add on your **model.rb**

```
aasm_column :your_column
```